# Ionic cordova run blank app istead of my app on android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I build my app with ionic cordova build android --prod it will normally create an apk. In www folder, it will create a bunch of js files with names like 2.c53507902fe252ca1911.js and 4 folders - assets, cordova-js-src, plugins, and SVG. The inside of the assets folder is my source of the app. But when I start the app on phone it will throw a blank project with text like create your new app with ionic or something like that and in the left top - BLANK. If I build the app only with Cordova or android studio, it normally works.

Can you please help me?